Remove part of x axis, keeping x axis limits
My graph displays text outside of existing values range on the x axis.
In order to get the text at the correct y level, I increased x axis limits using coord_cartesian.
I would like to remove part of the x axis, keeping the x limit of the plot.
My current reproducible code
### Loading library
library(ggplot2)

### Initiating data
data(iris)

### Initiating plot
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(4, 10)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=Species, x=9, label=Species)) + 
  theme_classic()


My aim

Not sure this is feasible

Note that geom_text(aes(y=Species, x=9, label=Species)) overplots the labels for each row of a species, which gives them this wonky bold look. Use annotate, or something like geom_text(aes(y=Species, x=9, label=Species), \(d) dplyr::distinct(iris["Species"]))

Oh I was wondering why the output was bold. For my real use I will label something else than y labels but thank you for the tip!

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(4, 10)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=Species, x=9, label=Species)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6,8)) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(cap = "upper"))



Didn't know this guides option, thank you !

Cool use of guide_axis(cap = "upper"), my initial thought was a coord_cartesian(clip = "off") and then increasing margins on the right, which is more tedious than what you have here
